# QGIS Python AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'processingRegistry'

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, attributeerror

I am executing a QGIS Desktop 3.8.3 Python 3 script.

```
from osgeo import ogr, gdal
from gdalconst import *
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils, sys
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFileInfo
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis", True)
QgsApplication([], True).initQgis()
sys.path.append('C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/python/plugins')
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
from processing.tools import *
```

Everything is working fine until the line `from processing.core.Processing import Processing`.

But, when the line `Processing.initialize()` is running, I am getting an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\QgisAlgorithmProvider.py", line 309, in load
QgsApplication.instance().processingRegistry().addParameterType(self.parameterTypeFieldsMapping)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'processingRegistry'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

How can I solve this issue?

Note that this issue only occurs in the latest version of QGIS (as on October 2019), that is QGIS Desktop 3.8.3. So, this is a particular issue related to QGIS and cannot be generalized as a software development issue.

Comment: I solved it. This is a issue with the latest version of QGIS. So, I added few commands and solved this after trying a lot. This question can't be generalized as a software development issue, instead it is purely a QGIS related issue.

Comment: what commands did you add to solve it? I am having the same problem.